# How to implement schema based multitenancy with micronaut

Tags: java, postgresql, multi-tenant, micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm starting to build a new webapp, it currently has an `AuthenticationProvider` which checks a user and password match what's in a database table. Its session based.

Currently micronaut just seems to use the public schema (I'm on postgres).

I've tried enabling a subdomain tenant resolver in my `application.yml`:

```
  data:
    multi-tenancy:
      mode: SCHEMA
      tenantresolver:
        subdomain:
          enabled: true
```

But I can't tell that it's doing anything. If I visit `subdomain.localhost` to test it a session cookie seems to appear tied to that subdomain, but any user from the public schema can authenticate against it. I assume my `AuthenticationProvider` needs to become tenant aware somehow?

If I then have another tenant sign up, who isn't authenticated at the point of registering, how would a schema get populated for them using micronaut data before they come to authenticate? Thanks.

Comment: I'm starting to think micronaut doesn't really have support for this and I need to look elsewhere. Annoying, it was probably the very last feature I was looking for from it.

Comment: What is your stack? There are some examples https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/tree/master/doc-examples/jdbc-multitenancy-schema-example-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else, I had two issues:

- Nginx was in front of micronaut and needed `proxy_set_header Host $host;` setting, else it was taking the subdomain from host.docker.internal which was always consistent and not from `abc.myhost.com` or `xyz.myhost.com` etc.
- tenantresolver in `application.yml` should be under multitenancy which sits on the same level as data.